# Create a date slicer in Power BI to keep dates between specified values and blank values

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, null, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to replicate a filter on a dashboard on Tableau. The filter ask for 2 paremeters: "Start_date" and "End_date". Then goes:

```
IF ISNULL [Date Column] THEN
1
ELSEIF [Date Column]>= [Start_date] AND [Date Column] <= [End_date] THEN
1
ELSE
0
```

The filter then filters all graphs for the value 1.

To replicate it in Power BI I created a simple date slicer for Date Column, but it does not consider Null Values.

On closer inspection, I noticed that [Date Column] does not have any Null value. The filter instead returns a 1 when the table cointening [Date Column] and Table2 related by the column [ID] does not contain an ID present on Table2.

How can I create the same filter?

I tried creating a calculated table separate from DateColumn unrelated to the data model to use for the slicer and a calculated column on Table1 to filter null values but it didn't work